# Uplaod Button background Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

here it is in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y3xyU/120/
and my questions is how to get rid of gray background?
preferably using pure css or Bootstrap only.

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector">
                            <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" style="display: none;">
                            Upload File...
                        </label>
                        <label class="sr-only">Public key</label>
                        <input type="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Public Key">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
.input-group-addon{
background:none !important;
}
```

to get rid of the grey background

Answer (score 0):

So you have many choices:

1. Edit bootstrap CSS for all the website that use this CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/y3xyU/121/

```
.btn-primary {
color: #fff;
background-color: grey;
border-color: grey;
```

2. make a specia rules for this button (make a special class or something like that that is pointed by custom css with other color)

http://jsfiddle.net/y3xyU/123/

```
.btn-primary-grey {
color: #fff;
background-color: grey;
border-color: grey;
```

3. make special css inside this html file especially and put it with stronger css selector or the !important hack

(same code as 1 but not on bootstrap css, just on this page)

If you want to remove the color, see @SameerShaikh response : background:none;

Comment: This will override all other primary buttons. I think a new btn-* class better solution